# Android app linking open in webview leads to endless loop

Tags: android, webview, navigation, applinks, android-app-links

On my project we are using an [app-linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) approach, however, we are still, unfortunately, forced to open these links in a webview (native implementation is on away).
So let's say this is my pattern `https://login.domain.com/user_authz.oauth2?user_name={name}` in an intent filter.
 Asset links are set properly and I can open my Login Activity.
Now I have to open the same link/pattern in a webview to allow the user to login, though I end up in an endless loop and the activity keeps open itself